Not saying Amen to the brachas - Ki Tavo
In Parashat Ki Tavo starting 27:15, a list of curses are read by the Levites and it explicitly mentions that the whole nation answered Amen
A few verses later when mentioning the blessings there is no mention that the whole nation said Amen
The Gemara in Sota on 37b states:

וּלְהַקִּישׁ בְּרָכָה לִקְלָלָה, לוֹמַר לָךְ: מָה קְלָלָה בִּלְוִיִּם,
אַף בְּרָכָה בִּלְוִיִּם. וּמָה קְלָלָה בְּקוֹל רָם, אַף בְּרָכָה
בְּקוֹל רָם. וּמָה קְלָלָה בִּלְשׁוֹן הַקּוֹדֶשׁ, אַף בְּרָכָה
בִּלְשׁוֹן הַקּוֹדֶשׁ. וּמָה קְלָלָה בִּכְלָל וּפְרָט, אַף בְּרָכָה
בִּכְלָל וּפְרָט. וּמָה קְלָלָה — אֵלּוּ וָאֵלּוּ עוֹנִין וְאוֹמְרִים
״אָמֵן״, אַף בְּרָכָה — אֵלּוּ וָאֵלּוּ עוֹנִין וְאוֹמְרִים ״אָמֵן״.
And furthermore, the verse comes to juxtapose the blessing with the
curse, to say to you that just as the curse is recited by the Levites,
so too, the blessing is uttered by the Levites; and just as the curse
is proclaimed loudly, so too, the blessing is proclaimed loudly; and
just as the curse is proclaimed in the sacred tongue, Hebrew, so too,
the blessing is proclaimed in the sacred tongue; and just as the curse
is proclaimed both in general and in detail, so too, the blessing is
proclaimed in general and in detail. And just as after the curse is
uttered, both groups of people on each mountain respond and say amen,
so too, after the blessing is uttered, both groups respond and say
amen.

Anyone know why the Torah didn’t explicitly say it? I understand that the Gemara learns that we can learn one from the other but I am wondering why the Torah didn’t specifically mention it
I haven’t seen any commentators comment on this (if anyone knows of any I would love to know)
Thank you

"A few verses later when mentioning the blessings" Are those blessings said by the levites? If they are then why is there another set of curses afterwards?

How do you explain the Gemara in Sotah that says that they answered Amen to the blessings? Are you suggesting there was another set of blessings that was mentioned by the Levites that was not recorded in the Torah to which they responded the Amen that they Gemara speaks about?

That's what the Mishna says https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%98%D7%94_%D7%96_%D7%94

Thanks @DoubleAA
